# ‘Service unavailable’ on ColdFusion 8 application service

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have often faced the issue ‘Service unavailable’ in ColdFusion website and need to restart the service manually. Sometimes, also need to restart the host computer.

I checked Event Viewer but I do not find any error related ColdFusion.

I am not familiar with ColdFusion. 
Kindly help me. I would like to check why it happens and to solve this issue.

ColdFusion Version 8

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard - Windows 7, 64bit

IIS Version 7.5

Thank you.

Comment: I'd start with looking into what version of Java you're running on.  You should be able to find it in the CF Admin.

Comment: Java 6 Standard Edition is running in host computer. I do not find any error message in Debugging & Logging > Log Files (CF Admin).

Comment: When it happens to us, it's usually because the server is being overwhelmed with too many long running page requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what is *actually* crashing your CF server you *may* find information in the "out" log. Look in the /runtime/logs directory for a file called "coldfusion-out.log" or something similar. This is where standard out goes in a running CF application. There is also a /logs directory in your application that may give additional information.

Finally, you may have a hotspot error - an abend. Look in the /runtime/bin directory for a file similar to hs_err_pidXXX.log" (where XXX is some number). If you do have such an error take a quick look to see if it is an "out of memory" error. That's the most common.

I have a post on where all those [log files are located](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2005/6/23/coldfusion_logs). It is from the CF8/CF9 days so it may be useful to you. Of course everyone will tell you to upgrade as well. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are two places to look with problem like this: the application server behind CF (JRun for CF8) is the connector between CF and IIS. Adobe CF uses old (IIS6?) style ISAPI connectors that may need to be rebuilt - later versions of CF have a 'rebuild connectors' batch file in cfusion\bin\connectors (something like IIS_connector.bat) but it has been a while since I've had CF8 to look at. At the very least, be certain that you have the last CF8 update from Adobe as they sometimes want you to rebuild connectors after installing them.

A better solution for newer versions of CF (10+) is to use Bilal's [Boncode AJP connector](http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/) - I don't think it supports CF8 but haven't tried it.

CF 8's End-Of-Life was over four years ago and later versions stopped using JRun in favor of Tomcat, which is a bit easier to troubelshoot. If you have a development environment available, you might try running your codebase on CF10 or CF11; if you have to support this application for the foreseeable future, better to do it on something resembling a current version of CF. You could also have a look at Lucee 4.5 for an OSS alternative.